# creating custom order from admin in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I am using prestashop. Is there any solution by which admin can create custom order from admin panel for specific user? also admin can use custom price. when the specific user is logged on, he can view that custom order and pay money for it.

Answer (score 1):

For this thing you must buy a module... search google for Telephone Order Prestashop or New Order Prestashop and there is couple of modules (some of them actually cost money)

check this out http://www.prestashop.com/forums/viewthread/19388/third_party_modules/super_module_new_order_1_dot_0/

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible by default in version 1.5 :)

Comment: Can you provide a reference to back up that claim?

Comment: http://www.prestashop.com/blog/en/prestashops-new-v1-5-rc1-is-now-available/ - Place or modify orders from the Back-office - This feature allows merchants to help customers over the phone and place the order for them.